# Listview go to main when i click in item

Tags: android, listview

I have an app that has a `ListView` and when I click on some item, it adds the item in an array.

But when I click on some item I don't want change the view, then in Android 4.0 the `ListView`going to first, but in Android 4.2.2 the `ListView` doesn't change. Why?
I always want the same result, the second option.

Is there any property for this?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Could you explain a little more ? maybe some code ?

Comment: When I click on the listview, the list returns to the top in Android 4.0, and i don't want to move. This error does not happen in Android 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making use of the getFirstVisiblePosition() and setSelection() methods of the listView. The first gets the first listview item present on the screen and the second moves the listview to the proper index when you comeback to this activity.
Please read the documentation for some more details about these functions.